# How to duplicate table row based on column value in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

Can someone help this task? If I have one table as below in Teradata:

| caseid | content | repeat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | row1 | 2 |
| id2 | row2 | 3 |

I want to build a new table based on the repeat value as below. How should I do?

| caseid | content | repeat | groupid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | row1 | 2 | 1 |
| id1 | row1 | 2 | 2 |
| id2 | row2 | 3 | 1 |
| id2 | row2 | 3 | 2 |
| id2 | row2 | 3 | 3 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teradata proprietary EXPAND ON syntax creates time series and can be used for this task:

```
SELECT t.*
   -- convert period back to int
  ,End(pd) - Current_Date AS groupid
FROM mytable AS t
-- works on date/time only -> convert int to period
EXPAND ON PERIOD(Current_Date, Current_Date + repeat) AS pd
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using recursive cte :

> ```
> with recursive cte as (
> select * , 1 groupid from cases 
> union all 
> select caseid ,content, repeat, groupid + 1 groupid
> from cte 
> where groupid  < repeat
> )
>
> select  * from cte
> order by caseid
> ```

> ```
> caseid | content | repeat | groupid
> -----: | :------ | -----: | ------:
>      1 | row1    |      2 |       1
>      1 | row1    |      2 |       2
>      2 | row2    |      3 |       1
>      2 | row2    |      3 |       2
>      2 | row2    |      3 |       3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e158c661b38dbb64db259bcf1917c7c)*